# Devise sanitiser not permitting parameters for sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've followed this documentation to allow users to sign in with a username or email address using the parameter 'login':

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address

My database contains three users. Any time I try to sign in, no matter which account, it's the first user that always gets signed in. I think that the cause is somehow related to the permitted parameters for sign_in in the Devise sessions controller:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  def create
    # Inspect params here...
    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    render json: {success: true,
                  jwt: current_token,
                  message: "Authentication successful" }
  end

  protected

  def configure_sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:login, :password])
  end

  ...
end
```

Inspecting the parameters shown at the point marked in the comment above will give (note the 'permitted: false'):

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"user"=>{"login"=>"second_user", "password"=>"secret"}, "controller"=>"users/sessions", "action"=>"create", "session"=>{"user"=>{"login"=>"second_user", "password"=>"secret"}}} permitted: false>
```

As far as I can tell based on https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/ParameterSanitizer this should be working, so please let me know if you can spot anything wrong that relates to this issue.

Comment: on the github page it tells to override the `find_for_database_authentication` method in the `User` model. Did you do that? If yes, can you post the code?

Comment: Thanks for replying. My code for `find_by_database_authentication` is as per the tutorial linked to above. Strangely, although I'm still seeing the "`permitted: false`" error I have managed to fix the login issue by setting `config.skip_session_storage = [:params_auth]` in the devise initializer.